# Slim syntax inside "vue.js template" attribute or javascript template literals

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phoenix-framework, slim-lang, template-literals

When you are defining a template for a component, is it possible to use `slim template` syntax?

```
template: `
  <div class="component">
    <%= @conn.assigns.somevar =>
  </div>
  `
```

This is not working, it`s handled like a string, is there any way to escape this?

Comment: Perhaps a more suitable title would be how to use slim template syntax in Javascript Template literals

Comment: Yes, I have used only these ones in vue, but its must be more generic.